# JQuery: find child elements from an existing selector

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Im sure the solution is simple but I cant figure it out :(
I need to combine two jquery selectors in one selector:

```
$(this) + $('input[type=text]:first')
```

$(this) is e.g div#selected so the result should be:

```
$('div#selected input[type=text]:first').focus();
```

How to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use [**`.find()`**](http://api.jquery.com/find/):

> Get the descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements, filtered by a selector.

```
$(this).find('input[type=text]:first').focus();
```

or set the [**context**](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#selector-context) to `this`:

```
$('input[type=text]:first', this).focus();
```

Comment: Thank you. Knew it was easy :)

Answer (score 3):

You can use multiple comma-separated selectors:

http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/

Answer (score 1):

I ***think*** you are looking for:

```
$('input[type=text]:first', this).focus();
```

It will focus the input box in the context of `div#selected`

Comment: Thank you. Knew it was easy :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).children('#inpouter[type=test]:first').focus();
```

Should do the trick...

Comment: That's not exactly the same.  It will only search the immediate children of the first selector.  The example only cares if the element is a descendent of the first selector.

Comment: True, I guess I made that assumption. The other answers are better here anyway (e.g. find)