# Grouping jquery slectors

Tags: jquery, css-selectors

Is there a way to group jquery selectors together?

```
$(':text, #password').keypress(function() {
```

Comment: yes there is... http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: you already grouped them with `$(':text, #password')`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer should work as it is written, below are some addition links regarding combining jQuery selectors:

[Multiple Selection - jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/multiple-selector/)

[StackOverflow - Combining two jQuery Selectors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896938/jquery-combine-two-jq-selectors)

Comment: this makes no sense because element with id `#password` may only appear once in dom, so `:text` selector is useless

Answer (score 0):

If I got it right I guess it's

```
$(':text#password').keypress(function() { alert("hello"); });
```