# jQuery selectors: targeting inputs in a form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following:

```
$('#registration_form input[type=text], #registration_form input[type=password]')
```

And I feel it can be much better: faster and shorter

Something like

```
$('#registration_form input[type=text,password]')
```

---

**EDIT:  [THIS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896938/jquery-combine-two-jq-selectors)** is what I really wanted! Please take a look [here](http://api.jquery.com/find/)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have isn't bad, if you really wanted "cleaner" syntax you could try this:

```
$("#registration_form").find("input[type=text], input[type=password]")
```

Slightly cleaner, but not necessarily faster. It has to find #registration_form just once now instead of twice, but you're adding a second method call in there. Also since you're already matching on an exact id, you're likely going to save very little processing time in my example above.

Comment: I consider your syntax more readable for designers and jQuery newcomers, so I award you

Comment: I use Python approach in my code: readability is better then code size

Answer (score 4):

You can use [find()](http://api.jquery.com/find/) with the [:text](http://api.jquery.com/text-selector/) and [:password](http://api.jquery.com/password-selector/) selectors to shorten your syntax:

```
$("#registration_form").find("input:text, input:password")
```

From a performance standpoint, it might be slightly faster, but not by much.

**EDIT:** Since `:text` and `:password` are not native CSS selectors, the following variation using [filter()](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) might be faster (and it's shorter in the first place):

```
$("#registration_form input").filter(":text, :password")
```

Comment: This almost certainly won't be faster, though. Cleaner and simpler, sure, but likely not faster. I doubt the registration form has the hundreds or thousands of elements required to notice that kind of efficiency change, though :P.

Comment: @Stefan, indeed, I don't think changing the selector can improve performance much. I actually parsed that requirement as "faster *to type*" :)

Comment: The official docs warn against this one as well. Specifically that this is jQuery specific syntax and that means it cannot take advantage of native optimizations. Specifically: "queries using :text cannot take advantage of the performance boost provided by the native DOM querySelectorAll() method. For better performance in modern browsers, use [type="text"] instead."

Comment: @Michael, good point, it looks like the shorter the code gets, the slower it runs :)

Comment: Look at ChristopheCVB's answer. I'll send John Resig a wish letter ))))

Comment: Yup, these days I tend to hold the opinion that in 99% of cases the compiler/parser/engine will have enough optimizations in it not to matter. After all, early optimization is usually a distraction anyways - especially in webapps where network latency trumps most other things! :)

Comment: That's quite odd. I would think the implementation would change `:text` to `[type=text]` and then use `querySelectorAll`. I wonder what the meta selectors are doing.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid such selector doesn't exist. However you can use a class if you want to simplify your selector.

Comment: That's what I will do now. But I'll chose other answer as more informative