# How to apply further selectors after storing selected objects

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

I want to re-use jQuery selections to be able to do further sub-selections. This is my example:

```
if ($('#thisId > .thatClass').length > 0) {
    return $('#thisId > .thatClass > a.thatOtherClass').attr('id');
}
```

As I make extensive use of selections, I want (at least for readability reasons) to shorten the code to look similar to this:

```
var selection = $('#thisId > .thatClass');
if (selection.length > 0) {
    var furtherSelection = selection.filter('> a.thatOtherClass');
    return furtherSelection.attr('id');
}
```

Trying this I get an error:

> TypeError: furtherSelection.attr(...) is undefined

Clearly I've got something wrong, maybe someone has an idea?

Comment: That's the actual error? That doesn't make sense to me.

Comment: your example doesn't make sense.. so what happens when you get more than one element?  You only want to return one id?

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery: find child elements from an existing selector](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2896938/jquery-find-child-elements-from-an-existing-selector) ... in your case you can use `.children`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Us `children()` instead...

```
var selection = $('#thisId > .thatClass');
if (selection.length > 0)
{
    return selection.children('a.thatOtherClass').attr('id');
}
```

I've used `children()` due to the fact that the use of `>` in selectors is to be deprecated (as per comments below).

If you weren't looking specifically for child elements then you could use `find()` like this...

```
var selection = $('#thisId > .thatClass');
if (selection.length > 0)
{
    return selection.find('a.thatOtherClass').attr('id');
}
```

Comment: Use `.children()` instead of `.find()` with a selector that starts with `> ...`. jQuery will deprecated that use  of that selector.

Comment: `Note: The $("> elem", context) selector will be deprecated in a future release. Its usage is thus discouraged in lieu of using alternative selectors.`  http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/

Comment: @Archer: thx for your answer, this was exaclty what i was looking for!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `.children()` instead as Archer suggests, [and you should](http://api.jquery.com/child-selector/). But the root problem is that you're using `.filter` when you mean `.find`. Archer hints at this, but it's important to understand that there was no problem with your `("> a.thatOtherClass")` construct other than best practice.

`filter` doesn't traverse the DOM tree; it removes elements from the current sequence, *at the same DOM level*. So, when you wrote this:

```
var furtherSelection = selection.filter('> a.thatOtherClass');
```

You were really saying "elements that satisfy `'#thisId > .thatClass'` **AND ALSO**  `'> a.thatOtherClass'`." So you were testing your middle `.thatClass` elements when you should have been testing their children. If you had used `find` or `children` instead, it would have worked:

```
var furtherSelection = selection.find('> a.thatOtherClass');   //works
var furtherSelection = selection.children('a.thatOtherClass'); //also works
```

See these in action on jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/jmorgan123/S726f/

I'm pointing this out because the difference between `.filter` and `.find` is very important, and your real problem was that you were confusing the two.